# Draw Logic Circuits using python's schemdraw

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators, digital-logic, schemdraw

I want to draw this equation with schemdraw '(PB01) and (not LT02)'

I Get something like this[image].

here's my code :

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.logic as logic

# Create a new drawing

d = schemdraw.Drawing()

# Add the PB01 input

PB01 = d.add(logic.Line().left().label('PB01', loc='left'))

# Add the AND gate with label 'b' at 'in1'

and_gate = d.add(logic.And().label('b', loc='in1'))

# Add the LT02 input, with a NOT gate

LT02 = d.add(logic.Line().left().at(and_gate.in2).label('LT02', loc='left'))

# Add a NOT gate connected to the AND gate's second input

not_gate = d.add(logic.Not().at(LT02.end).right())
d.add(logic.Line().at(not_gate.out).to(and_gate.in2))

# Draw the output
d.add(logic.Line().right())

# Display the drawing
d.save('text.png')
```

how to arrange everything the right way ?

Thanks !